# Firestore .NET client library authentication in Azure Function

Tags: c#, google-cloud-firestore, azure-functions

I am using Google.Cloud.Firestore version 1.0.0-beta22 in a C# Azure Function app. The documentation states to create a service account json file and create a GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable pointing to this json file.

My issue is I don't want to add the json file to my source repository, and even if I did I don't know the path to the directory that the Azure Function will be running in, thus I am unable to set the environment variable.

Is there a way to pass the credentials to the Firestore client library, or any other workarounds to address this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After much googling I've found that you can create a credential from Json and use this to create a FirestoreClient which you then pass to the FirestoreDb.

```
 var credential = GoogleCredential.FromJson(<JSON AS STRING>);
 var channelCredentials = credential.ToChannelCredentials();
 var channel = new Channel(FirestoreClient.DefaultEndpoint.ToString(), channelCredentials);
 var client = FirestoreClient.Create(channel);
 var firestoreDb = FirestoreDb.Create("project id", client);
```

Comment: I figured out how to use FirestoreDbBuilder and EmulatorDetection to connect to the local firestore emulator. It depends on the environment variable FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST which in my case is localhost:8008. I'm wondering if Channel and your technique might work. I may try that tonight.

Comment: Did you get it to work with the emulator too? For the emulator which credentials did you use?

Comment: @JackFox Are the credentials from a service account?

Comment: yes the credentials are from a service account

Comment: Great help. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It is simplified in version `2.0.0` (`Google.Cloud.Firestore`)

```
 FirestoreDb firestormDb = new FirestoreDbBuilder
                {
                    ProjectId = "project id",
                    JsonCredentials = "<JSON AS STRING>"
                }.Build();
```

Comment: Fyi, you can also use this technique to connect to a local Firestore emulator.